# Serializing XML with flat repeating structure

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to serialize some XML to an object.  I don't have control over the structure of the XML so I'm stuck with this situation.  The structure is similar to this example:

```
<A>
  <B>Elements that are the stuff of B</B>
  <C>Stuff about the stuff in B</C>
  <B>Different stuff</B>
  <C>Stuff about the different stuff</C>
  <C>Some more stuff about the different stuff</C>
  <B>Weird stuff</B>
  <C>Stuff about the Weird Stuff</C>
  <C>Still more stuff about the Weird Stuff</C>
  <D>New thing that goes with the Weird Stuff</D>
  <B>Things</B>
  <C>Stuff about Things</C>
 </A>
```

I'd like to get this serialized to an object that maintains the information about the sibling structure.

```
public class A
{
 public List<BCD> BCD {get; set;}
}

public class BCD
{
 public B Bfield {get; set;}
 public List<C> Cfield {get; set;}
 public D Dfield {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
 // class details
}

public class C
{
 // class details
}

public class D
{
 // class details
}
```

When I try this, it doesn't work.  Is there anything I can do to maintain that structure using the XMLSerializer?

Comment: A, B and C are object (complex elements in XML) or Strings?

Comment: B,C,D are complex elements.  My example poorly demonstrates that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kept looking around for a solution and came up with this which is not exactly what I was looking for. This class structure retains the order of the sibling elements within the collection but does not create objects to represent a discrete group of the siblings.

```
public class A
{
 [XmlElementAttribute("B", typeof(B))]
 [XmlElementAttribute("C", typeof(C))]
 [XmlElementAttribute("D", typeof(D))]
 public List<object> BCD {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
 // class details
}

public class C
{
 // class details
}

public class D
{
 // class details
}
```

The end result is BCD is a collection of the B,C,D objects in the order they appear in the XML.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below steps:

1. convert your xml to xslt using xsd.exe(feature of VS)
2. convert xslt to class again by using xsd.exe
3. try to serialize and deserialize your xml to this class object.
4. now you can play with this class object to perform any action.

Hope this will help..